# Fixed nav issues

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, fixed, nav

I have a client that want's two custom nav menus stacked on top of one another and under a slider with their logo in the center. They also want the menus to be fixed upon scroll. I have executed this and it works amazingly. Here is the link... [DEMO](http://www.jshuadvd.com/din8/)

Now here lies the conundrum. Although this looks great on any device over 1200px, for the life of me I am not able to figure out how to make this look great for devices below that. I have added media queries to almost all of the code and still noting. I have made everything else on the page responsive except for this. Maybe removing the fixed menu is an option for smaller devices??? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code.... BTW I know the code is sloppy and in abundance, any suggestions to clean it up are welcome....

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav-container">

<div id="nav-box" class="animated fadeInDown">

<a class="btn rounded butter" href="#">Start Dinating</a>
<a class="btn rounded butter" href="#">Follow Us</a>
<a class="btn rounded butter" href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
<a class="btn rounded butter" href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>  
<a class="btn rounded butter" href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a> 
<a class="list-group-item" href="#"></a>
<img src="http://www.jshuadvd.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo.png" alt="Dinate" width="199" height="204">
<a class="btn2 rounded butter" href="#">Merchandise</a>
<a class="btn2 rounded butter" href="#"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Log In / Register</a>
<a class="btn2 rounded butter" href="#"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>View Tab</a>

</div>

<nav id="second-nav">

<div id="nav-left">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">OUR RESTAURAUNTS </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DINATING EVENTS </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="nav-right">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BLOG </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CHARITES </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
            #nav-container {
              height: 180px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 15px;
              font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
              text-transform: uppercase;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-container {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               font-size: 12px;
               }
            }


            #nav-box {
              position: relative;
              background: #222;
              text-align: center;
              width: 100%;
              height: 50px;
              z-index: 2000;
              padding-top: 0px;
              padding-bottom: 5px;
              line-height: 0;

            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-box {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }


            #nav-box img {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 50%;
              margin-left: -100px;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-box img {
               display: none;

               }

            }



            /* --------------------- BUTTTONS ------------------- */



            .btn {
              overflow: hidden;
              position: relative;
              display: inline-block;
              height: 2em;
              line-height: 2em;
              padding: 0 1em;  
              left: -7.5%; 
              margin: 10px 30px 0 0; 
              -moz-transition: color 400ms;
              -o-transition: color 400ms;
              -webkit-transition: color 400ms;
              transition: color 400ms;
              }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .btn {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               font-size: auto;
               }

            }


            .btn2 {
              overflow: hidden;
              position: relative;
              display: inline-block;
              height: 2em;
              line-height: 2em;
              padding: 0 1em;  
              left: 9.8%; 
              margin: 10px 30px 0 0; 
              -moz-transition: color 400ms;
              -o-transition: color 400ms;
              -webkit-transition: color 400ms;
              transition: color 400ms;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .btn2 {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               font-size: auto;
               }

            }


            .btn:before {
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              z-index: -1;
              height: 0%;
              width: 100%;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              -moz-transition: height 100ms;
              -o-transition: height 100ms;
              -webkit-transition: height 100ms;
              transition: height 100ms;
              }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .btn:before {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }


            .btn2:before {
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              z-index: -1;
              height: 0%;
              width: 100%;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              -moz-transition: height 100ms;
              -o-transition: height 100ms;
              -webkit-transition: height 100ms;
              transition: height 100ms;
              }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .btn2:before {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }



            .btn:hover {
              color: #A4C739;
              border-color: #A4C739;
              }


            .btn2:hover {
              color: #A4C739;
              border-color: #A4C739;
              }


            .btn:hover:before {
              height: 100%;
              }


            .btn2:hover:before {
              height: 100%;
            }

            .rounded {
              border-radius: 2em;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .rounded {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               border-radius: auto;
               width:auto;

               }

            }

            .butter {
              color: white;
              border: 3px solid white;
              border-radius: 2em;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .butter {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               border-radius: auto;
               width:auto;

               }

            }


            .butter:before {
              background-color: #A4C739;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .butter:before {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:auto;

               }

            }

            .butter:hover {
              color: white;
              border-color: white;
            }



            /* ---------------- SOCIAL NAV ICONS ------------------ */

            .icon-facebook {
              margin-left: -10px;
              margin-right: -10px;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .icon-facebook {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width: auto;
               }

            }

            .icon-twitter {
              margin-left: -10px;
              margin-right: -10px;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .icon-twitter {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:auto;
               }

            }

            .icon-instagram {
              margin-left: -10px;
              margin-right: -10px;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .icon-instagram {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width: auto;
               }

            }


            /* ---------------- BUTTON ICONS ------------------ */

            .icon-shopping-cart {
              margin-right: 6px;
              margin-left: -4px;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .icon-shopping-cart {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:auto;
               }

            }

            .icon-lock {
              margin-right: 5px;
              margin-left: -4px;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              .icon-lock {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:auto;
               }

            }


            .clear {
              clear: both;

              }


            /* ---------------- BUTTONS END ------------------ */


            /* ---------------- SECOND NAV ------------------- */
              #second-nav {
              width: 100%;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 15px;
              font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
              text-transform: uppercase;  
              z-index: 999;
              }



            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #second-nav {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               font-size: 12px;
               }

            }


            /* ----------------- LEFT NAV ------------------- */


            #nav-left {
              z-index: 1;
              margin-bottom: -92px; /* nav height */
              padding: 5px 60px;
              background: #000;
              transition: box-shadow 400ms; 
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-left {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }

            #nav-left ul {
              margin:0 auto;
              width:100%;
              list-style: none;
              *zoom: 1;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-left ul {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }

            #nav-left ul:after {
                clear:both;
                display: table;
                content: "";
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-left ul:after {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }


            #nav-left li {
              float: left;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 0 45px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
              -moz-border-radius: 4px;
              border-radius: 4px;
              list-style: none;
              border-left:1px solid #222;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-left li {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               border: none;
               }

            }


            #nav-left li:first-child {
              border-left: 0;
              padding-left: 0;
             }


            #nav-left a {
              position: relative;
              display:block;   
              color: #fff;
              padding: 40px 0;
              line-height: 1px;
              text-decoration: none;
              -moz-border-radius: 4px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
              border-radius: 4px; 
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-left a {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               border: none;
               }

            }    

              #nav-left a:hover {
              color: #A4C739;
            } 


            .clear {
            clear: both;

            }


            /* --------------- RIGHT NAV ---------------- */

            #nav-right {
              z-index: 1;
              margin-bottom: -72px; /* nav height */
              padding: 0 120px; 
              background: #000;
              transition: box-shadow 400ms; 
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-right {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }


            #nav-right ul {
              margin:0 auto;
              width:100%;
              list-style: none;
              *zoom: 1;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-right ul {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }

            #nav-right ul:after {
                clear:both;
                display: table;
                content: "";
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-right ul:after {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               }

            }

            #nav-right li {
              float: right;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 0 45px ;
              -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
              -moz-border-radius: 4px;
              border-radius: 4px; 
              list-style: none;
              border-right:1px solid #222;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-right li {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               border: none;
               }

            }

            #nav-right li:first-child {
              border-right: 0;
              padding-right: 0;

             }


            #nav-right a {
              position: relative;
              display:block;   
              color: #fff;
              padding: 40px 10px;
              line-height: 1px;
              text-decoration: none;
              -moz-border-radius: 4px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
              border-radius: 4px; 
            } 


            @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
              #nav-right a {
               box-sizing: border-box;
               width:100%;
               text-align: center;
               border: none;
               }

            }   

              #nav-right a:hover {
              color: #A4C739;
            /*  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
              box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #fff; */
            }     


             .fixed {
                  position:fixed !important;
                } 



            .clear {
              clear: both;
            }
```

**JS / JQUERY**

```
    <!------------Begin JavaScript Functions for Fixed Header-------->

    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var aboveHeight = $('#slider').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
        $('#nav-box').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('margin-top','55px');
        } else {
        $('#nav-box').removeClass('fixed').next().css('margin-top','0');
        }

    });
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
        $('#second-nav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('margin-top','40px');
        } else {
        $('#second-nav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('margin-top','0');
        }

    });  
    });


    </script>

    <!------------End JavaScript Functions for Fixed Header---------->
```

Comment: Well not to bag on your coding skills but damn its sloppy. Ultimately I believe its why you are not getting the desired results. The media queries are working in your CSS but im pretty sure it gets lost in all the different calls. I made a fiddle of the code you provided and you can see in the CSS if you shrink the window the "leftnav" turns red. I suggest organizing your code or start from scratch and use a framework like bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/kop5kaqz/

Comment: Thanks Matt... As I mentioned in the post, the code is sloppy, but it's just the CSS. This is still a work in progress as you can see. Unfortunately starting over isn't an option as there is a deadline. You can also see that this is a very custom request per the client and it is a bit troubling. Can you offer a different way to accomplish what I need done? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to begin with standard media queries. Also you can use max-width or max-device-width depending upon your situation. It seems like all of your queries are just max-width beyond 1200px (large format). You need to figure out for each layout how the navigation will adapt. For a fixed layout, you will need to decrease each element proportionally. For example if you have five elements in a row at 1200px wide, for a 600px mobile screen, you would cut the widths of each in half.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) Styles */
}

@media only screen 
(max-width : 600px) {
/* Mobile Only Styles */
}
```

More info:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

If you look at the Twitter Bootstrap mobile first approach, they have these main breakpoints for devices of different widths because the mobile is the default CSS (not inside a media query):

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @768px) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

For you, though, you will want to use max-width a subtractive approach. If you know the max-width, you can size each navigation element proportionally.

```
    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
      .butter.btn-1 {width:128px; font-size: 12px;}

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
      .butter.btn-1 {width:105px; font-size: 10px;}
    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
      .butter.btn-1 {width:80px; font-size: 8px;}
    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
      .butter.btn-1 {width:50px; font-size: 6px;}
    }
```

http://scotch.io/quick-tips/css3-quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Bootstrap takes a mobile first approach, which is different than your HD first design. So, you can just think of it in reverse, which is to say that your 1200+ resolution is the default, and everything else needs to be modified. I understand this is not ideal, and not what I recommend, but you've said that you don't want to change all of that, so this is just a workaround.

Ultimately, I think the buttons on the fixed navigation are going to be too small. The other thing you should consider is the use of relative em widths instead of pixel widths. Again, the Bootstrap frameworks have a lot of these things worked out for you already so that sizes are already relative.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will look this over and see what I come up with. I did try to add the first one you suggested to no avail. I copy and pasted it to each query I already had. Am I doing something wrong? I had no problem making everything else Responsive.

Comment: So, I think what is missing is that you need to have three things. 1) A design for desktops -- this should be the normal base css with no media query at all. 2) A tablet media query as above if you want to treat tablets differently. Often this is not required, as most sites look fine. 3) A mobile media query -- which is designed for resolutions smaller than 800px or 600px wide.

Comment: Thanks for that. And which elements should the media queries be placed on? Furthermore, what would be a good solution to shrink the fixed navigation for the mobile devices?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer to include the Twitter Bootstrap media queries. What I recommend is to draw out on paper what each width looks like. Write out the IDs and classes for each element, and then inside the media queries you adjust each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and in depth answer. I am going to try this and see what results I come up with. I really appreciate all of your help. I'll let you know what the outcome is.

Comment: If you get stuck, just make a fiddle with only that part. Then we can tackle one thing at a time.